# i need to make a confusion matrix for a CNN model

Tags: python

hi im new to machine learning and i just wanted to know how to make a confusion matrix from this code i just followed the instructions on youtube and i think im lost i just need to plot the confusion matrix my data sets is all about cancer and has 2 categories with and withought cancer i just followed the video of sentdex and changed his data sets

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Users/Acer/imagerec/MRI"

CATEGORIES = ["yes", "no"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        break
    break
print(img_array)
print(img_array.shape)

IMG_SIZE = 50

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass


create_training_data()

print(len(training_data))

import random

random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])

X = []
y = []
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = numpy.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)



pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=5, epochs=1, validation_split=0.1)



model.save('64x2-CNN.model')
```

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify if you want to _plot_ a confusion matrix, or do you want a confusion matrix?

Comment: i need a visualization of the confusion matrix so ye like plot show XD from this code sorry im still pretty new with this and i dont know much about this stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you where the classifier predicted right/wrong on the *training data* (because there is not test set in your code).

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

pred = model.predict(X)

conf = confusion_matrix(y, pred)
```

```py
Out[1]: 
array([[5, 8], # rows are actual classes, columns are predicted classes 
       [9, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

To plot it (minimal example):

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(conf, annot=True)
```

[image: Heatmap]

Comment: Why strictly on training? Cant you also use it for validation data?

Comment: OP has not used a hold out set in his code. You could of course do the same with the test data, but OP doesn't have one at this time.

Comment: sorry i cant answer much im still really new with machine learning i was just following instructions on youtube on how to make an image classifier and this is where i got so far and now I just need a confusion matrix

Comment: hiya um idk sry im really bad at this hehe so where should i put the codes XD? i keep getting errors on pred = model.predict(X)

Comment: At the end completely!